# dyld : Library not loaded - How to make xcode look for library in a path

Tags: xcode, cmake, dyld

I am attempting to run my xcode project and I get this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libosgd.130.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/raj/MyApp-Build-XCODE/bin/Debug/MyApp2.app/Contents/MacOS/Myapp2
  Reason: image not found
```

My project .xcodeproj was created using CMake. I know where this library is present. How can I tell xcode to look for it in a specific path.I am fairly new to xcode 7.Here is what I tried.

I went into the build settings of the project.Expanded "Linking". Then expanded "RunPath Search Paths". Then inside the debug row underneath my project column added the path to the library such as

```
~/Mypaths/lib/
```

However I am stilling getting this error when I run project. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced this problem while I was using Alamofire library

The following step solved it for me:

[image]